# My button doesn't work when I open the html file but on CODEPEN it works?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering when I done a test on my button on my web page it works on codepen preview & JSFIDDLE but not when I open the html file for the same web page?

**CODEPEN EDITABLE LINK**

Here it works, if you download the code and export it as .zip when you open the html file it wont work. [Codepen editable preview](https://codepen.io/ldocherty1/pen/wdMEBW)

**PREVIEW 2**

Here is a preview of the same exact code in the editable preview shown above, it works in the editable preview but not the preview here? This is the same as if I would open it on a html file. [preview2 resemblance of how the button doesn't work when I open html file](http://codepen.io/ldocherty1/full/dWGjqQ)

**JSFIDDLE VIEW**

Here is a [JSFIDDLE of button](https://jsfiddle.net/cztrqcyr/) which works like the editable codepen link above but in the resemblance link it doesn't work same exact code.

I have resetting browsers, using different browsers (safari,chrome & firefox) & different computer systems with OS (macOS & Windows 10).

**Button code html**

```html
<div class="container text-center">
    <a href="../HTML%20web%20pages/About%20Me.html" target="_parent"><button>Find out more about me</button></a>
</div>
```

Incase someone says the button don't work due to them not having the file, replace the link with a vlid working html web page link & the result will still be the same it works on the editable codepen view & jsfiddle but not the preview2 which is the resemblance link above.

It seems like my H1 elements are covering up my button.

Comment: Checked your console…? *Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516768/my-button-doesnt-work-when-i-open-the-html-file-but-on-codepen-it-works' from frame with URL 'http://stacksnippets.net/js'. The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the 'allow-top-navigation' flag is not set.*

Comment: @deceze Thats because OP has set `target=_parent`, it will work if that is removed.

Comment: @Jones Soo… you've identified the problem…?! :)

Comment: @deceze No I dint `:p`. But i did understand the error in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your `<a>` element is behind the `<h1>` element, give the `<a>` element the following styles, then it should work:

```
a {
    color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It happened because one of your H1 elements are covering up your button, you can set `z-index` to your button, but better to bring the layout of your HTML into a correct structure.